# Change Text With Javascript on Offset Pages

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to change the h1 text from "Recent Posts" on the original /blog slug to "More Posts" on any subsequent offset urls like "/blog?offset=" Any ideas how to execute the change would be appreciated. This is just what I had gotten started with.

Thanks

```
<script type = "text/javascript">  
window.onload = function () {  
document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = "More Posts";  
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Do you intend to use the offset as the new H1 text? Like "/blog?offset=MorePosts"

Answer (score 0):

Get the parameters from your url, check if you have offset as a parameter and then set the value of your h1.

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if(searchParams.has('offset')) {
   // set your h1 text
}
```